# How to list products according to a sequence of categories (hierarchical)

Tags: mysql, database, recursion

I need to return the products according to a sequence of categories (slug column) entered by the user

I was told I should use *CTE (RECURSIVE)* but I don't have much database experience

*Category table*

[image]

*Product table*

[image]

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mRd9VYaY3H5srb8zWda5E/2)

---

**Examples (male):**

*slug ('male')*

- T-shirt male Tank top
- T-shirt male Basic shirt
- T-shirt male Basic shirt rose
- Pant male casual
- Pant male social

*slug ('male', 't-shirts')*

- T-shirt male Tank top
- T-shirt male Basic shirt
- T-shirt male Basic shirt rose

*slug ('male, 't-shirts', 'tank-top')*

- T-shirt male Tank top

*slug ('male, 'pants')*

- Pant male casual
- Pant male social

---

MySQL Version: 8.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

1 - Created a 'path' field in category table with the full path of each category ( male/... )

2 - Query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id FROM category WHERE path LIKE 'path%'
)
SELECT p.name, p.category_id, MIN(pd.price) AS price
FROM product p
    INNER JOIN cte
        ON (cte.id = p.category_id)
    INNER JOIN product_detail pd
        ON (pd.product_id = p.id)
WHERE p.active = 'yes' AND pd.stock > 0
GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with recursive cte` to get the hierarchal data as you mentioned, something like this:

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parent_category_id) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             parent_category_id
  from       category
  where      parent_category_id = 1 
  union all
  select     c.id,
             c.name,
             c.parent_category_id
  from       category c
  inner join cte
          on c.parent_category_id = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

The query above will get all hierarchical records where the `parent_category_id = 1`. The results in your case:

[image]

You can adjust the `Where` statement to suit your needs.

**EDIT**

To suit your specific use case, you can use two recursive ctes. The first to filter for male/female and the second to pull in the hierarchal data that you're looking for. You would need to pass the *first* slug value into the first cte, and the *last* slug value into the second cte expression:

```
with recursive first_slug (id, name, parent_category_id) as (
  select     category.id,
             category.name,
             category.parent_category_id
  from       category
  inner join (select id from category where slug = 'male') sq on sq.id = category.id 
  union all
  select     c.id,
             c.name,
             c.parent_category_id
  from       category c
  inner join first_slug
          on c.parent_category_id = first_slug.id
),
last_slug (id, name, parent_category_id) as (
  select     category.id,
             category.name,
             category.parent_category_id
  from       category
  inner join (select id from category where id in (select id from first_slug) and slug = 'pants') sq on sq.id = category.id
  union all
  select     c.id,
             c.name,
             c.parent_category_id
  from       category c
  inner join last_slug
          on c.parent_category_id = last_slug.id
)
  
select * from last_slug;
```

There could very possibly a cleaner or more efficient way to do this but this is the only way I can think of using only sql.

Comment: parent_category_id = 3 does not return the product "T-shirt male Tank top". It doesn't seem to work with the last level ( child )

Comment: The Male and Female category have the same subcategories (example: T-shirts). User need to input 'male', 't-shirts' to display men's t-shirts

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I am not sure exactly what you're going for but try running the query with `where id = 3` instead. Will there always be a male or female identifier in the slug?

Comment: With id it worked, the problem is that the user will inform the slug, not the id
This slug can be 'male', or 'male', 't-shirts' ( N words )
As I said, you can follow a sequence

Comment: In the question, I gave some examples of how the return would be and provided a link to the query ( in db-fiddle )

Comment: Yes I see that. I can see the sequence, my questions is - will the sequence always start with 'male' or 'female'? Or could you get a slug such as "'t-shirts', 'tank-top'" where you need to select both 'male' and 'female' results?

Comment: Will always start with 'male' or 'female'.
From the main category to the lowest level

Comment: See my updated answer.